# How can I find out what % of my users are viewing my page with it cached?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to find out how many of my users are visiting my pages with the page cached, but I'm new to GA (and web analytics in general) so wasn't sure if this was possible?

If not some relevant statistics to how many users navigate to websites with it cached would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Cached where ? Almost anybody with a browser will have a browser cache enabled. Plus if everything is cached the tracking pixel will not be sent to the server (after all that is what "cached" means) and you will not received data from the cached page.

Comment: Cached anywhere but our servers. I understand most people will have a browser cache enabled, I would just like to know when this is the case.